# How do you list all items in the undo record using a word vsto in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, undo

In Microsoft Word, as you type a document, items are added to the undo record:

[image: Example of Undo Record in Microsoft Word]

How can I list all items in the undo record through a vsto?  For example, in the above picture it would return "Typing "abc", "Grow Font", "Text Fill Effect".

So far, the closest I have gotten is [checking to see if the undo stack is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050257/how-do-you-check-to-see-if-the-undo-button-is-disabled-using-a-word-vsto-in-vb-n/76050258#76050258).  This still does not allow me to get the contents of the undo stack.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UndoRecord` object to create and modify custom undo records in the Word undo stack. Read more about that in the [Working with the UndoRecord Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-the-undorecord-object) article.

```
Dim objUndo As UndoRecord 
Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord
```

You may also find the [Undo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.undo) method which undoes the last action or a sequence of actions, which are displayed in the `Undo` list. Returns `true` if the actions were successfully undone. The [UndoClear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.undoclear) method clears the list of actions that can be undone for the specified document. This method corresponds to the list of items that appears when you click the arrow beside the Undo button on the Standard toolbar.

Comment: That is for setting custom undo records.  I am trying to read the list of (non custom) undo records.

Comment: There is nothing provided in the Word object model for that.